# variable output manipulation on what it outputs

Tags: php

hello is this code possible:

```
$y = 'Z';
$x = echo '$'.'y';
```

`echo $x`;

output of it is: **$y**

there are a lot of possible solution like using if statement,$x=$y etc but from this kind of approach can I change the output into: **Z**?
just using `echo $x;`

Comment: is this http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.variable.php what you're looking for?

Comment: using echo to initialize a variable isn't correct and will turn your code in error.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:

```
$y = 'Z';
$x = 'y';

echo $$x;
```

http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

hope the following helps.

```
$y = 'Z';
$x = ${"y"};
echo $x;
```